# AngularJS filter is not updating the dom when searching. Same filter works in another project of mine.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am trying to filter a basic table I created in angular. I used this same filter on a similar project, but wanted to replicate it for practice. Everything seems the same as my other project, but I cant figure out why this solution isnt working. Everything seems like it should work but the DOM never gets updated. Please see HTML and JS below

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Angular Sort and Filter</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
  body { padding-top:50px; }
</style>

<!-- JS -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="alert alert-info">

Sort Type: {{ sortType }}

Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}

Search Query: {{ searchPlayer }}

<table class="table table-bordered">
<h2>All Star Game Votes</h2>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in headers">{{ head.displayName }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="head in headers">
            <input type="text" ng-model="head.searchText"> 
          </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter: allSearch">
          <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ player.position }}</td>
          <td>{{ player.votes }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// app.js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
$scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
$scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order

// create the list of baseball players 
$scope.players = [
{ name: 'Aaron Judge', position: 'Right Field', votes: 98 },
{ name: 'Ryan Zimmerman', position: 'First Base', votes: 76 },
{ name: 'Paul Goldschmidt', position: 'First Base', votes: 87 },
{ name: 'Mike Trout', position: 'Center Field', votes: 89 },
{ name: 'Charlie Blackmon', position: 'Center Field', votes: 77 },
{ name: 'Bryce Harper', position: 'Right Field', votes: 67 },
{ name: 'Jose Altuve', position: 'Second Base', votes: 83 },
];
$scope.headers = [
{ displayName: 'Player Name'},
{ displayName: 'Position'},
{ displayName: 'All-Star Votes'}
];



//custom filter
$scope.allSearch = function (value, index, array) {
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.players.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.players[i].searchText && value[$scope.players[i].name]) {
      var searchTextLower = $scope.players[i].searchText.toLowerCase();
      var playersLower = value[$scope.players[i].name].toLowerCase();
      var isMatch = playersLower.indexOf(searchTextLower) > -1;
      if (!isMatch) {
          return false;
      }  
    } else if ($scope.players[i].searchText && !value[$scope.players[i].name]) {
      return false;
    }
}        
return true;
};

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that prevents this code from working:

1) You are using `$scope.players` array inside the loop, but you should use `$scope.headers`;

2) You should add property `name` to your `head` object like `{ displayName: 'Player Name', name: 'name'}`;

3) `value[$scope.headers[i].name]` can return something which could not be a string (for example number) and in this case you will get exception `toLowerCase is not a function`;

```js
// app.js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
$scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
$scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order

// create the list of baseball players 
$scope.players = [
{ name: 'Aaron Judge', position: 'Right Field', votes: 98 },
{ name: 'Ryan Zimmerman', position: 'First Base', votes: 76 },
{ name: 'Paul Goldschmidt', position: 'First Base', votes: 87 },
{ name: 'Mike Trout', position: 'Center Field', votes: 89 },
{ name: 'Charlie Blackmon', position: 'Center Field', votes: 77 },
{ name: 'Bryce Harper', position: 'Right Field', votes: 67 },
{ name: 'Jose Altuve', position: 'Second Base', votes: 83 },
];
$scope.headers = [
{ displayName: 'Player Name', name: 'name'},
{ displayName: 'Position', name: 'position'},
{ displayName: 'All-Star Votes', name: 'votes'}
];



//custom filter
$scope.allSearch = function (value, index, array) {
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.headers.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.headers[i].searchText && value[$scope.headers[i].name]) {
      var searchTextLower = (''  + $scope.headers[i].searchText || '').toLowerCase();
      var playersLower = ('' + value[$scope.headers[i].name] || '').toLowerCase();
      var isMatch = playersLower.indexOf(searchTextLower) > -1;
      if (!isMatch) {
          return false;
      }  
    } else if ($scope.headers[i].searchText && !value[$scope.headers[i].name]) {
      return false;
    }
}        
return true;
};

});
```

```css
 body { padding-top:50px; }
 table input { color: black; }
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!-- JS -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="alert alert-info">

Sort Type: {{ sortType }}

Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}

Search Query: {{ searchPlayer }}

<h2>All Star Game Votes</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in headers">{{ head.displayName }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="head in headers">
            <input type="text" ng-model="head.searchText"> 
          </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter: allSearch">
          <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ player.position }}</td>
          <td>{{ player.votes }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** Instead of using this function for filtering, you can use an object. [From the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects
>   contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will
>   return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and
>   property phone containing "1".

So your code could look more simple, just let angularjs to do the job:

```js
// app.js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order

    // create the list of baseball players 
    $scope.players = [
      { name: 'Aaron Judge', position: 'Right Field', votes: 98 },
      { name: 'Ryan Zimmerman', position: 'First Base', votes: 76 },
      { name: 'Paul Goldschmidt', position: 'First Base', votes: 87 },
      { name: 'Mike Trout', position: 'Center Field', votes: 89 },
      { name: 'Charlie Blackmon', position: 'Center Field', votes: 77 },
      { name: 'Bryce Harper', position: 'Right Field', votes: 67 },
      { name: 'Jose Altuve', position: 'Second Base', votes: 83 },
    ];
    $scope.headers = [
      { displayName: 'Player Name', prop: 'name'},
      { displayName: 'Position', prop: 'position'},
      { displayName: 'All-Star Votes', prop: 'votes'}
    ];

    $scope.searchAll = {};
});
```

```css
body { padding-top:50px; }
table input { color: black; }
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!-- JS -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="alert alert-info">

Sort Type: {{ sortType }}

Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}

Search Query: {{ searchPlayer }}

{{searchAll}}

<h2>All Star Game Votes</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in headers">{{ head.displayName }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="head in headers">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchAll[head.prop]"> 
          </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter:searchAll">
          <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ player.position }}</td>
          <td>{{ player.votes }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me, can you tell me why this wont filter numbers in the votes column??? it says value[$scope.headers[i].name].toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: Glad to help. I want to update the answer and show an example on how your code could be simplified. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: im sure the solution to the numbers is something dumb im overlooking

Comment: awesome! this was beyond helpful and I understand this completely. Thanks for taking time to help an angular newbie! I am really trying to understand these little nuances  so i can become more proficient